# Cannot remove /dev/null when upgrading

Tags: apt, package-management

When I upgrade my Ubuntu desktop, I have this message

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
rm: cannot remove '/dev/null': Permission denied
```

I never saw this before upgrading to 18.10 (I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 almost a year ago), and the messages appeared as soon as I have finished the upgrade.

I saw the same message on my debian 10 desktop I use at home, (I never saw it on Debian 9), but the message appeared later (after 2/3 month)

Comment: So, this is on 18.10 ?